# Why EGLConfig in both eglCreateContext() and eglCreateWindowSurface()?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

On Android (if it matters) when creating an OpenGL context I need to pass in an `EGLConfig` to `eglCreateContext()`. Then when I want to create an `EGLSurface` from a native window I need to call `eglCreateWindowSurface()` and it too takes an `EGLConfig` as a parameter.

What is the relationship between the 2 `EGLConfig`s?

I'm sure I'm missing something because it seems like you could potentially provide conflicting `EGLConfig`s with different `EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE` for example. I don't understand why you need to pass in an `EGLConfig` to both functions and whether or not they have to be somehow compatible.